# Qt: QPushButton never shows up

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to learn Qt, with a fairly simple application:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDebug>

/* -- header begin {{{ */
class BareBase {
    public:
        BareBase();
};

class BareBones: public QApplication {

    private:
        BareBase* base;

    public:
        BareBones(int &argc, char **argv);
        ~BareBones();
};
/* -- header end }}} */


/* -- implementation begin {{{ */
BareBase::BareBase()
{
    QPushButton hello("Hello world!");
    hello.resize(100, 30);
    hello.show();
}

BareBones::BareBones(int& argc, char** argv): QApplication(argc, argv)
{
    qDebug() << "Creating new instance ... ";
    base = new BareBase();
}

BareBones::~BareBones()
{
    qDebug() << "Cleaning up ... ";
    delete base;
}

/* -- implementation end }}} */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //Q_INIT_RESOURCE(files);
    BareBones app(argc, argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```

Now, the problem is that the Button created in `BareBase` never shows up, and i'm puzzled why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your QPushButton is creating and display correctly but go out of scope when leaving BareBase constructor. Using a member variable or a pointer will solve your problem.

If you use a pointer, you should add your button to its parent. By this way the button will be automatically deleted when the parent will be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

`QPushButton` might have shown up but not in the visible area of the widget. That's why, you should add all your widgets to the **Layouts** that are available in Qt to obtain the desired behaviour. Check out the docs [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/layout.html)... It has examples also...

Also, basically you will be having a base [`QWidget`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwidget.html) or most probably [`QMainWindow`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qmainwindow.html) on which all your controls will be present.. So, your `QPushButton` will be in the *parent* widget.. Your `QApplication` will contain your application specific information like setting the window, setting the font for your entire application kinda stuff..

Hope it helps..

Comment: not too sure if I understood that, but I'll check out the docs. the examples there look promising.